# Spring Cloud Stream is not sending messages to RabbitMQ, instead consumes in the same pod. Producer and Consumer are in the same app

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream and RabbitMQ, and I have configured both the producer and consumer in the same application, but using two different channels. The problem is that I have five replicas of my app running on Kubernetes, but only the pod that sent the messages that consumes them, the other four doesn't consume. On RabbitMQ console, there's no messages being received, the Message Rate graph doesn't change. When I comment the OrdersListener, the messages are successfully send to the RabbitMQ cluster. Does anyone know what may be wrong?

Below is the Producer Channel:

```
@Component
public interface OrdersChannel {
   @Output("Orders")
   MessageChannel publishOrders();
}
```

And here is the Consumer Channel:

```
@Component
public interface OrdersListenerChannel {
   String BINDING = "Orders";

   @Input(BINDING)
   SubscribableChannel input();
}
```

Here is the Service that produces the messages:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableBinding(OrdersChannel.class)
public class OrdersEventService {

    private final OrdersChannel ordersChannel;

    public void sendOrderEvents(final Set<Order> orders) {
        orders.parallelStream().forEach(order ->
            ordersChannel.publishOrders()
            .send(message(OrderMessageDTOBuilder.build(order))));
    }

    private static <T> Message<T> message(T val) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(val).build();
    }
}
```

And here's the Listener:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableBinding(OrdersListenerChannel.class)
public class OrdersListener {

    private final OrderService orderService;

    @StreamListener(OrdersListenerChannel.BINDING)
    public void listen(final OrderMessageDTO orderMessageDTO) {
       // orderService method call
    }
}
```

And my application.properties are like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.Orders.destination=GeneralExchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.Orders.producer.requiredGroups=OrdersQueue
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.Orders.producer.bindingRoutingKey=OrdersQueue
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.Orders.producer.routingKeyExpression='OrdersQueue'


spring.cloud.stream.bindings.OrdersListenerChannel.group=OrdersQueue
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.OrdersListenerChannel.consumer.max-attempts=3
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.OrdersListenerChannel.consumer.concurrency=10
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.OrdersListenerChannel.consumer.bind-queue=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.OrdersListenerChannel.consumer.republish-to-dlq=false
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there are couple of questions you're asking.
First, your configuration and programming model (annotation-based) is long deprecated and actually will be removed in the next major release. We have longed switched to [functional programming model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-producing-consuming-messages) which is significantly simpler.

With regard to your replicas. . . I don't think that has anything to do with what you are observing. You are effectively saying that you have five consumers, but only one receives a message. This means you do not have pub-sub model configured in RabbiotMQ. This resembles miss-configuration or miss-understanding of RabbitMQ relationship between the exchange type and routing key to the queue. Your exchange must be of type `topic` routing properly to the bound queues (e.g., `#` as a routing key)